# IIS URL Rewrite: Rewrite if file in specific path doesn't exist

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a seemingly easy requirement of IIS' URL Rewrite module that I can't seem to get working for a Single Page Web App.  I have a root folder `content` and inside there is a folder `dashboard`.  The URL uses `dashboard` at the root (i.e. `content` is omitted from the URL). If a URL matches any file, I'd like it to serve that, otherwise, I'd like it to serve `index.html` in the dashboard folder.  The only complication is that dashboard is inside the `content` folder in the filesystem but `content` doesn't exist in the URL.

Here's my folder structure:

`/content/dashboard/foo.txt` --> serve this for URL: `/dashboard/foo.txt`

`/content/dashboard/assets/image.jpg` --> serve this for URL: `/dashboard/assets/image.jpg`

`/content/dashboard/index.html` --> serve this for any URL that starts with `/dashboard/` if there isn't a file that matches

Here are my rewrite rules:

```
    <rules>
        <rule name="dashboard assets" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^dashboard(.*)$" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="content/{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="false" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="content/dashboard{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="dashboard app" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^dashboard(.*)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="content/dashboard/index.html" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
```

Even though I have the `dashboard assets` conditions above, it never seems to use it and always serves index.html.  How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

{REQUEST_FILENAME} returns the full local directory path for the file requested. e.g. /content/dashboard/assets/image.jpg variable {REQUEST_FILENAME} is actually C:\inetpub\wwwroot\content\dashboard\assets\image.jpg

Remove the content/ from your condition input and it should work fine.